# nativescript passing props vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

Having trouble passing a prop in nativescript this.$navigateTo()

```
 <template>
       <stack-layout v-for="meme in memes">
        <Image :src="meme.url" @tap="goToEditPage(meme.url)"/>
       </stack-layout>
      </template>

<script>
import EditMeme from './EditMeme'
  export default {
    computed: {
      memes(){
        return this.$store.getters.memes
      }
    },
    components: {
      EditMeme
    },
    methods: {
      goToEditPage(ImageUrl) {
        this.$navigateTo(EditMeme, { context: { propsData: { Image: ImageUrl } }});
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

I tried passing props [this way](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues/178)

still, In the child component I get an undefined ,
this is the child component :

```
  export default {
props: ['Image'],
methods: {
  onButtonTap() {

    console.log(this.props);
  }
  }}
```

Any ideas? I'm new with vue.js so there is a good chance I'm missing something basic in my code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to navigate is this:

```
this.$navigateTo(confirmRoute, {
                    props: {
                        hospital: "hospital A",
                        startpoint: "startpoint Y",
                        endpoint: "point x"
                    }
                })
```

You just need to catch it like this then or you next page:

```
 props: ['hospital', 'startpoint', 'endpoint'],
```

and you can use it then like this in the JS:

```
this.hospital
this.startpoint
this.endpoint
```

If you wish to use it in the template you need to this:

```
<template>
    <Page>
            <Label  :text="$props.hospital.name">
            </Label>
        </FlexBoxLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case using nativescript vue:

`@tap="$navigator.navigate('/settings/your_page', {props: { isEditMode: true }})"`

In the your_page.vue:

`props: {  isEditMode: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: false } },`

`mounted() { console.log("isEditMode :>> ", this.isEditMode); }`